# For each ip try a list of urls

Tags: vb.net

Now i have:

Dim i As Integer

```
Dim web As New WebClient With {.Proxy = Nothing}
'http://1.2.3.4/sql.db
Dim attkstring As String = "/sql.db"
i = 0
Dim shellx As Integer = 0
Dim sUrl As String = shells.Items(shellx) & attkstring
For Each item In shells.Items
    Try
        If web.OpenRead(sUrl) = True Then

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    shellsloadedtext.Items.Add(sUrl)
    shellx += 1
Next
```

But in my ListBox write all (ip+url), I need to write the IP + the URL just in case work, and now writes them even if there are no

Ex: real ip: 7.7.7.7 false ip: 1.1.1.1

I write in the ip list 7.7.7.7 1.1.1.1

And my ListBox shellsloadedtext wirte 7.7.7.7/sql.db and 1.1.1.1/sql.db

Help me

Comment: Please post a new question as a separate question. You can reference this one if you want. StackOverflow is not a help forum. It's a Q/A website. You have a question - you get an answer. Another question - another answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

```
Dim sUrl As String = ips.Items(urlchk) & urlstring
web.DownloadString(sUrl)
yourListBox.Items.Add(sUrl)
```

Reference:

- [HTTP GET with .NET WebClient](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33798/HTTP-GET-with-NET-WebClient)

Comment: why 
Dim result As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
yourListBox.Add(result)
?

Comment: @SemWilliamCersosimo: Sorry I forgot you need the list of URLs in your listbox. Also [DownloadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw(v=vs.110).aspx) is much easier than dealing with streams. Check my edit.

Comment: Now I'm on break soon as I finish I try. Thanks you very much

Comment: @SemWilliamCersosimo: Also you don't need `urlchk` in this context, you can just use item (since you already have it), like this: `Dim sUrl As String = item & urlstring`.

Comment: you can write to my email?

Comment: @SemWilliamCersosimo: I can, but I don't see why I should.

Comment: because i need help; when i insert: 
mylistbox.Add(sUrl) he say an error

Comment: 'Add' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox'

Comment: @SemWilliamCersosimo: Make it `.Items.Add` then.

Comment: @SemWilliamCersosimo: Please don't forget to accept my answer then. If you have a new question, please ask it separately. Me or someone else may be able to help you.

Comment: i have accpeted you answer and thanks for the support :)